# configurable values not getting from config.toml when bal test

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I have some configurable values in my ballerina project. It is a ballerina service.

```
public configurable string[] validScopes = ?;
public configurable string[] validAlgorithms = ?;
```

To set the configurable I'm using a config.toml file like below.

```
validScopes = ["accounts","payments"]
validAlgorithms = ["HS256","HS384","HS512","RS256","RS384","RS512","ES256","ES384","ES512"]
```

When I run the project using `bal run` command then it working fine. But when I use `bal test` command to run the unit test then I'm getting an error `error: value not provided for required configurable variable 'validScopes'`.

Is there any config we have to put in the test.bal file to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/structure-tests/

Configurations for testing can be provided using configurable variables. The values for configurable variables can be provided in a file named `Config.toml` located in the tests directory.

For information on using configurable variables, see https://ballerina.io/learn/configure-ballerina-programs/configure-a-sample-ballerina-service/

Answer (score 0):

For testcases, you have to add `Config.toml` separately under `tests` folder.